# PHP change int to string

Tags: php, string, int

I'm pulling data from a database table using php.  I'm creating a simple string that provides information to a chart.

Here is the current code and out put:

```
$tsq7a = "SELECT * FROM FactDayUtilv1";
$stmt7a = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsq7a);

$data7a = "";                                                       
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt7a, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){  
$data7a .= "{name: '";
$data7a .= "$row[2]";
$data7a .= "', y: ";
$data7a .= "$row[3]";
$data7a .= ", drilldown: 'D";
$data7a .= "$row[2]";
$data7a .= "'},";
}
$data7a = substr($data7a,0,strlen($data7a)-1);
```

Creates the following output.

{name: '1', y: 65, drilldown: 'D1'},{name: '2', y: 66, drilldown: 'D2'},{name: '3', y: 54, drilldown: 'D3'},{name: '4', y: 71, drilldown: 'D4'},{name: '5', y: 43, drilldown: 'D5'},{name: '6', y: 12, drilldown: 'D6'},{name: '7', y: 8, drilldown: 'D7'}

I'm trying to replace the  '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' in the output to the days of the week as below:

{name: 'Mon', y: 65, drilldown: 'D1'},{name: 'Tue', y: 66, drilldown: 'D2'},{name: 'Wed', y: 54, drilldown: 'D3'},{name: 'Thu', y: 71, drilldown: 'D4'},{name: 'Fri', y: 43, drilldown: 'D5'},{name: 'Sat', y: 12, drilldown: 'D6'},{name: 'Sun', y: 8, drilldown: 'D7'}

I've been trying str_replace or str_ireplace with no luck.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Sidenote: There's a special function - `json_encode` that will encode you data properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create array;

```
$days = array(1=>'Mon',2=>'Tue'); //..
```

then change

```
$data7a .= "$row[2]";
```

to

```
$data7a .= $days[$row[2]];
```

Comment: Baaah!  That's too easy ;-)

Comment: sorry, shall i write the OOP version using the command line call to cobol?

Comment: Yes please, static class using `exec` to call PERL regex for replacement.

Comment: That worked - It really was that simple! as a newbe I think I'm expecting things to be harder than they are!  cheers Dagon